# How to set DNS when the device is connected via Ethernet?

Tags: android, networking, dns, resolver, ndc

My android target is connect via Ethernet using static IP.
I am able to connect it by using ADB, but I am not able to ping any server.
Please tell me how can I configure my DNS setting so that I can ping any server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this Command by superuser

**su**

*for versions before marshmallow 6.x*

ndc resolver setifdns (interface) (dns1) (dns2)

e.g.- **ndc resolver setifdns eth0 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4**

*for versions from marshmallow 6.x*

ndc resolver setnetdns (interface) (dns1) (dns2)

e.g.- **ndc resolver setnetdns eth0 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4**

Comment: Is there any changes to this command for Android 10? Its seems not working for me.

Comment: This answer is outdated. There is not `ndc resolver` anymore in latest android. You can search for `NdcNetdCommand(` in this repo <https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/> for more info. And `NdcDispatcher::NdcDispatcher` and `NdcDispatcher::dispatchCommand` shows you how is everything working.

Answer (score 2):

Android 8.0

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
ifconfig usb0 192.168.225.3 netmask 255.255.255.0

ndc network create 9792

ndc network interface add 9792 usb0

ndc network route add 9792 usb0 0.0.0.0/0 192.168.225.1

ndc resolver setnetdns 9792 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

ndc network default set 9792
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Hi @taras or anybody do you know how to make this on Android 10? The resolver has been moved and no longer exists that commands.

Comment: @jabella, sorry - no idea. I don't even remember how I found this solution:)